# ELK data pod keep on getting into crashloopbackoff

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, elk

I have implemented ELK on k8s, however my data pod keep on getting into crashloopbackoff status.

```
[]$ kubectl get pod -n  es
NAME                                               READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
logging-es-opendistro-es-client-76ff944d-rwjvz     1/1     Running            0          134m
logging-es-opendistro-es-data-0                    0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   3          18m
logging-es-opendistro-es-data-1                    0/1     Init:1/2           0          5m24s
logging-es-opendistro-es-kibana-5cfbd8dc49-g5rdl   1/1     Running            0          39m
logging-es-opendistro-es-master-0                  1/1     Running            0          134m
logging-es-opendistro-es-master-1                  1/1     Running            0          127m


Logs from data pod
[2021-02-15T08:02:46,683][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [logging-es-opendistro-es-data-1] loaded plugin [opendistro_security]
[2021-02-15T08:02:46,683][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [logging-es-opendistro-es-data-1] loaded plugin [opendistro_sql]
[2021-02-15T08:02:47,027][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [logging-es-opendistro-es-data-1] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (//fbeff48040de841b395c700.file.core.windows.net/kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-0f5e7e46-5138-0dfbe0aadff3)]], net usable_space [37.1gb], net total_space [50gb], types [cifs]
[2021-02-15T08:02:47,027][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [logging-es-opendistro-es-data-1] heap size [4gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
```

Comment: What is this registry url pointing to https://mmm/v2/infrastructure/busybox/manifests/1.27.2 ?
And is mmm an dns entry? How will be this name solved?

Comment: Image URL is fine, pod is getting into running state

Answer (score 0):

`Failed to pull image "/infrastructure/busybox:1.27.2"`. Your image name looks wrong. The image name is not supposed to start with a `/`.

You can check this [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#image-names) if you need to fetch an image from a specific registry.

Comment: Image URL is fine